# Editing a wordpress loop to bring in one page via its ID number

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

This loop brings in all the pages and shows it on a single page. How can I edit it so that I only bring in one page identified by its ID? (the page wont change)

```
Thanks       


 <section id="<?php echo $post->post_name;?>" class="page-area<?php echo $bgClass;?>"<?php echo $style;?>>
       <div class="wrapper"<?php if($fullEmbed<>''):?> style="width:100%"<?php endif;?>>
         <?php if($hideTitle!='Yes'):?>
           <hgroup class="title">
              <h1<?php echo $font;?>><strong><?php echo $mainHeading;?></strong></h1>
              <?php if($subHeading<>''):?><p<?php echo $font;?>><?php echo $subHeading;?></p><?php endif;?>
           </hgroup>
         <?php endif;?>
         <?php if($fullEmbed<>''):?>
           <div class="full-embed"><?php echo van_shortcode($fullEmbed);?></div>
         <?php else:?>
           <div class="entry"<?php echo $font;?>>
           <?php van_content(true,true);?>
           </div>
          <?php endif;?>
       </div>
    </section>

 <?php endwhile;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like:

```
<?php 
$page_id = 123; // 123 should be replaced with a specific Page's id from your site, which you can find by mousing over the link to edit that Page on the Manage Pages admin page. The id will be embedded in the query string of the URL, e.g. page.php?action=edit&post=123.

$page_data = get_page( $page_id ); // You must pass in a variable to the get_page function. If you pass in a value (e.g. get_page ( 123 ); ), WordPress will generate an error. By default, this will return an object.

echo '<h3>'. $page_data->post_title .'</h3>';// echo the title

echo apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content); // echo the content and retain WordPress filters such as paragraph tags. Origin: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/get_pagepost-and-no-paragraphs-problem
?>
```

Straight from the WP Codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page

Comment: Well it was more a case of editing the above to call in the page id. Just using the code below obviously calls in the page but not the formatting of the above.

Comment: You know the old saying: Teach a man to fish in the wordpress codex.

Comment: Ah, a philosopher. I was rather hoping to find a programmer to give me a few hints on understanding how to apply the codex to the above. Thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I just don't have too much time on my hands.
So I have to weight how much time I use everywhere.

BTW. You might be able to pull this off without coding, if your template has widgets on the front page, of if you can set your theme to display just a given content. It depends on your theme though. I'd check that first though :-)

Doing custom programming on a theme I have no clue about, is like drawing in the dark, without seeing the canvas. I can of course reverse engineer some of the HTML, yet I dont know about the functions.php in your theme and it's filters.